# How to find the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+}\left (1 - \frac{1}{x}\right)^x \left( \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{x}\right) + \frac{1}{x - 1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} \left (1 - \frac{1}{x}\right)^x \left( \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{x}\right) + \frac{1}{x - 1}\right)$?

I tried turning into a fraction so that I could apply L'Hopital's rule:
$\left(1 - \frac{1}{x}\right)^x \left(\frac{\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{x}\right)(x-1) + 1}{x - 1}\right)$

But that didn't seem to get me anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change variables to $y=\frac{x}{x-1}$, then $x=\frac{y}{y-1}$. Then your limit becomes:
$$
\lim_{y\to+\infty}\exp\left[\log (y-1-\log y)-\frac{y}{y-1}\log y\right]
$$
Now subtract $\log y$ from each of the terms to obtain:

$$
\lim_{y\to+\infty}\exp\left[\log \left(1-\frac{1+\log y}{y}\right)-\frac{\log y}{y-1}\right]=\lim_{y\to\infty}\exp(\log (1-0)-0)=\boxed{1}.
$$

Comment: To clarify:
You can subtract log(y) from each of the terms because you're looking at the limit of the difference of two terms?
And the last step is using L'Hopital's rule (or just prior knowledge) to say that y grows faster than log(y)?

Also, is there a heuristic you use to know when to apply the change of variables or exp(log()) techniques?

Comment: The change of variables was mostly for myself, because I have an easier time visualizing limits to $\infty$ instead of limits to $1$.

Doing $\exp\circ\log$ will help you out any time you are evaluating the limit of a product. It is especially useful when the product already involves a $\log$!

Answer (score -1):

let
$$I=\lim_{x\to 1^{+}}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^x\left(\ln{\left(1-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}+\dfrac{1}{x-1}\right)$$
Let $x=t+1$$$\Longrightarrow I=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{t+1}\right)^{t+1}\left(\ln{\dfrac{t}{t+1}}+\dfrac{1}{t}\right)=I_{1}\cdot I_{2}$$
since
$$I_{1}=\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{t+1}\right)^{t+1}=1$$
because  apply L'Hopital's 
$$I_{1}=\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}e^{(t+1)[\ln{t}-\ln{(t+1)}]}=1$$
and
$$I_{2}=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\ln{\dfrac{t}{t+1}}+\dfrac{1}{t}\right)=1$$
becasue  apply L'Hopital's 
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{t\ln{t}-t\ln{(t+1)}}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\left(\ln{\dfrac{t}{t+1}}-\dfrac{t}{t+1}+1\right)=1$$